# R: Using the sort function in a dataframe based on multiple columns

Tags: r

I am a cardiologist and love coding in R - i am having a real issue with sorting a data frame and i suspect the solution is really easy!

I have a data frame with summary values from multiple studies df$study. Most studies have only one summary value (df$summary). However as you can see Study A has three summary values (df$no.of.estimate). See below

```
study <- c("E", "A", "F", "A", "B", "A", "C", "D")
no.of.estimate <- c(1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1)
summary <- c(1, 2, 3, 5, 6 ,7 ,8 ,9)
df <- data.frame(study, no.of.estimate, summary)
```

So i want to sort the dataframe by `df$summary` - which is easy. However, if each study has more than one estimate then i want to group these studies together and appear in order using the "no.of.estimates" column.

So essentially the desired output is

```
study <- c("E", "A", "A", "A", "F", "B", "C", "D")
no.of.estimate <- c(1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1)
summary <- c(1, 7, 2, 5, 3 ,6 ,8 ,9)
df <- data.frame(study, no.of.estimate, summary)
```

Comment: You must have noticed that by using `cbind`, have created a matrix with columns as character class.  Use `data.frame(study, no.of.estimate...)`

Comment: You don't want to sort you whole data set by `sudy` and `no.of.estimate` rather only in case the `no.of.estimate` has more than one value? It seems like you overcomplicating this a bit. It seems like you could just do `df[with(df, order(study, no.of.estimate)), ]`, though take a look on @akruns comment first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
     mutate(study=factor(study, levels=unique(study))) %>%
     arrange(study,no.of.estimate)
  #  study no.of.estimate summary
  #1     E              1       1
  #2     A              1       7
  #3     A              2       2
  #4     A              3       5
  #5     F              1       3
  #6     B              1       6
  #7     C              1       8
  #8     D              1       9
```

Or a `base R` approach

```
df$study <- factor(df$study, levels=unique(df$study))
df[with(df, order(study, no.of.estimate)), ]
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(study = structure(c(5L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
4L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), class = "factor"), 
no.of.estimate = c(1, 2, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1), summary = c(1, 
2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)), .Names = c("study", "no.of.estimate", 
"summary"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

The expected dataset is

```
df1 <- structure(list(study = structure(c(5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 6L, 2L, 3L, 
4L), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), class = "factor"), 
no.of.estimate = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1), summary = c(1, 
7, 2, 5, 3, 6, 8, 9)), .Names = c("study", "no.of.estimate", 
"summary"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's my `data.table` attempt while leaving your columns as is and creating a new index (though see my comment first). It's main advantage that you will update your data set by reference rather than creating new copies

```
library(data.table)
setorder(setDT(df)[, indx := .GRP, study], indx, no.of.estimate)[]
#    study no.of.estimate summary indx
# 1:     E              1       1    1
# 2:     A              1       7    2
# 3:     A              2       2    2
# 4:     A              3       5    2
# 5:     F              1       3    3
# 6:     B              1       6    4
# 7:     C              1       8    5
# 8:     D              1       9    6
```